# Flutter - Delete a particular field from a document in cloud firestore?

Tags: flutter

How can I delete a particular field from a cloud firestore document?

Anyone Suggest me how to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Order to delete a particular field from a cloud firestore document - make sure you are using **Plugin version 0.8.0 or Above.** Now a
E.g If you have an Document having Field 'Desc' with contain some Text. In Order to Delete it.

```
Firestore.instance.collection('path').document('name').updateData({'Desc': FieldValue.delete()}).whenComplete((){
  print('Field Deleted');
});
```

This will Delete 'Desc' Field from the Document 'name'